# Does extended_bounds works with missing aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a date histogram on `missing` aggregation. The histogram runs fine except that the usual `extended_bounds` doesn't seem to work on it.

Query -

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "startTime": {
                  "gte": 1507700824000,
                  "lte": 1508305624000
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "perHost": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "queue"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ts": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "startTime",
            "interval": "1h",
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "extended_bounds": {
              "min": 1507700824000,
              "max": 1508305624000
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "numQuery": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "queryId",
                "precision_threshold": 500
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "perHostMissing": {
      "missing": {
        "field": "queue"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ts": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "startTime",
            "interval": "1h",
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "extended_bounds": {
              "min": 1507700824000,
              "max": 1508305624000
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "numQuery": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "queryId",
                "precision_threshold": 500
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample data -

`perHost` bucket first bucket data -

```
{
    "key_as_string": "2017-10-11T05:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1507698000000,
    "doc_count": 0,
    "numQuery": {
      "value": 0
    }
}
```

`perHostMissing` first bucket data

```
{
    "key_as_string": "2017-10-11T21:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1507755600000,
    "doc_count": 2,
    "numQuery": {
      "value": 1
    }
}
```

If you notice the `key` ( timestampe ), they are not same.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should provide the query you're running and some sample data that makes you think it doesn't work.

Comment: @Val posted query and data. Thanks!